# Rearrange / transpose array items by keys diagonally in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, key, diagonal

I have an array of **strings**, for example:

```
var arr=["dog", "cat", "bear", "wolf", "lynx", "hare", "sheep", "owl", "hen"];
```

To refer to any of these values, there are corresponding keys from 0 to 8, i.e. the arr[3] corresponds to "wolf". The amount of items of the actual array may vary and have more than 100 items in it. In this example there are 9 `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

What I would like to accomplish is to rearrange the items by their keys diagonally, i.e. from:

```
[0,1,2,
 3,4,5,
 6,7,8]
```

into:

```
[0,2,5,
 1,4,7,
 3,6,8]
```

i.e. into `[0,2,5,1,4,7,3,6,8]`, and thus also the sequence of the corresponding values from the original:

```
var arr=["dog", "cat", "bear", "wolf", "lynx", "hare", "sheep", "owl", "hen"];
```

resulting into the rearranged values:

```
var arr2=["dog", "bear", "hare", "cat", "lynx", "wolf", "owl", "sheep", "hen"];
```

The use of this solution would be implemented in more complex visualization of string items (strings each consisting of binary digits that correspond to UTF-8 encoded values of another data) in square shape, arranging them diagonally specifically from the left top corner. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can we assume that the square root of the Array's length will always be an integer?

Comment: blex, In case if the square root is a float number, it is rounded up — Math.ceil() — to the closest integer. And the empty string items "" of array, in order to complete such integer, are to be appended to the diagonal right bottom corner of array.

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: what means *diagonally*? what do look like a 5x5 square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took some time for me to get the math right, but I was able to make a function which returns an Array of indexes in the correct order:

```js
function getDiagonalArrayIndexes(length) {
  const sqrt = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(length));
  
  const formula = (x, y) => (y + x) * (y + x + 1) / 2 + x;
  
  return Array.from({ length: sqrt*sqrt }, (_, i) => {
    let x = i % sqrt, y = Math.floor(i / sqrt);
    
    if (x + y < sqrt) {
      return formula(x, y);
    } else {
      return length - 1  - formula(sqrt - 1  - x, sqrt - 1  - y);
    }
  })
  // In case length's square root is not an integer
  .concat(new Array(length - sqrt * sqrt).fill(null));
}

printSquare( getDiagonalArrayIndexes(9) );
printSquare( getDiagonalArrayIndexes(16) );
printSquare( getDiagonalArrayIndexes(25) );                                                                                       /* Just for the demo */ function printSquare(n){const o=Math.sqrt(n.length),t=[];for(var e=0,a=0;e<n.length;e++)e>=o&&e%o==0&&a++,t[a]=t[a]||[],t[a].push(n[e]);console.log("[\n"+t.map(n=>n.map(n=>("  "+n).slice(-3)).join(",")).join(",\n")+"\n]")}document.body.innerHTML="<style>\n  .as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }\n</style>";
```

You can then reuse it and map the indexes using your data:

```js
function reorderDiagonally(arr) {
  return getDiagonalArrayIndexes(arr.length)
         .map(i => i !== null ? arr[i] : '');
}

var arr = ["dog", "cat", "bear", "wolf", "lynx", "hare", "sheep", "owl", "hen"];

console.log(JSON.stringify( reorderDiagonally(arr) ));                                                                                                                   /* Just for the demo */ function getDiagonalArrayIndexes(r){const t=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(r)),n=(r,t)=>(t+r)*(t+r+1)/2+r,l=Array.from({length:t*t},(l,a)=>{let e=a%t,o=Math.floor(a/t);return e+o<t?n(e,o):r-1-n(t-1-e,t-1-o)});return l.concat(new Array(r-l.length).fill(null))}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `path` method, gives valid diagonal path for given [row, col]
2. `diagonals`, aggregate paths for starting on first column and last row.
3. Simple `map` to shuffle based on the diagonal paths generated.

PS: Not tested the cases where array length is not perfect square.

```js
const path = (row, col, len, res) => {
  while (row > -1 && col < len) {
    res.push([row, col]);
    row--;
    col++;
  }
  return res;
};

const diagonals = (len) => {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    path(i, 0, len, res);
  }
  for (let j = 1; j < len; j++) {
    path(len - 1, j, len, res);
  }
  return res;
};

// const input = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const input = ["dog", "cat", "bear", "wolf", "lynx", "hare", "sheep", "owl", "hen"]
const len = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(input.length));

const output = [...input]
diagonals(len).map(([row, col], i) => output[row * len + col] = input[i]);

console.log(output.join(', '));
```